# Node.js ZPAQ lib (or if none any other JavaScript ZPAQ implementation)

Tags: javascript, file-compression, node.js

I'm looking for a JavaScript implementation or wrapper for the [ZPAQ](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1005/107) archive format.

Requirements:

- **Strong Preference:** [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) addon.
- **Preferably:** a [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) addon but I'm really not expecting someone to have one of those hanging around. (*For those that don't know this means that it is a Node.js addon since Grunt Addons is a subset of Node.js addons*)
- Open Source

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a complete answer but node.js allows for [c and c++ add-ons](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/addons.html) you could then grab the [zpaq c++ source](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html) and try loading it into node.js as an add on. I haven't worked with c++ enough to help much more but that might be your best bet. Might require some tinkering and troubleshooting but I imagine it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work for you, but i'm developing a NodeJS wrapper for Uharc. Uharc is not paq, it is bsc. But it is free and it's 10% faster than paq4.

It uses wine to run in Linux and OSX as uharc is closed source and windows only.

https://github.com/ghaschel/node-uharc

Answer (score -2):

Doesn't exists. There is currently only the cpp version.

According Google and the zpaq website at bottom which lists related projects

http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html

Or the zpaq updates thread:

http://encode.ru/threads/456-zpaq-updates

Comment: Can you back your claim a little? Mentioning the cpp version indicates you did at least some research on that, but what makes you sure you might not have missed something? /// To downvoters: [Saying "that software/solution does not exist" is a perfectly acceptable answer to a question asked in good faith — that is assuming you can say so authoritatively.](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/696/185)